# Go postgresql LIKE query

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I'm working with Go and PostgreSQL (pq driver), I have the following query

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
FROM products AS p
WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE %$1% ORDER BY p.rate DESC
```

If I exec this query directly in PostgreSQL it work but in Golang says:

```
pq: syntax error at or near "%"
```

How can I fix it? I tried with "\%" but didn't works.
thanks.

here is the complete source code

```
func FindByName(name *string) ([]*Product, error) {
    db, err := db.StablishConnection()
    if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
            panic(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()

    query := `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
        FROM products AS p
        WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE %$1% ORDER BY p.rate DESC`

    product_rows, err := db.Query(query, name)

    if err != nil {
            return nil, err
    }

    if product_rows == nil {
            return nil, errors.New("No Products Named " + *name)
    }

    products := []*Product{}
    for product_rows.Next() {
            product := new(Product)
            err = product_rows.Scan(&product.Id,
                    &product.Name,
                    &product.Description,
                    &product.Price,
                    &product.Image,
                    &product.Rate)
            if err != nil {
                    panic(err)
            }
            products = append(products, product)
    }
    return products, nil
}
```

Answer (score 49):

You need to put the `like` pattern in single quotes:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
FROM products AS p
WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'
ORDER BY p.rate DESC;
```

Comment: now it says:
pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0
as if it doesn't recognize the $1

Comment: Wouldn't you need `LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'` in order for the placeholder to be recognized as a placeholder? Or do the string concatenation in Go and use `LIKE $1`.

Comment: `LIKE '%' || $1 || '%'` works, `'%?%'` says pq: got 1 parameters but the statement requires 0

Comment: Can confirm: `WHERE name LIKE %?%` does not work. Results in `near "%": syntax error`. The answer is: `WHERE name LIKE '%'||?||'%'`.

Comment: Confirm WHERE name LIKE '%'||?||'%' works with sqlite3

Comment: @AndySong . . . If you have a question about SQLite, then don't use an answer to a Postgres question.  But, I do believe that it should work in SQLite.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I was struggling of how to use LIKE and % in golang with sqlite3 and came across this post. Saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is the most correct way of doing this:

```
query := `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
    FROM products AS p
    WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE CONCAT('%%',$1::text,'%%') ORDER BY p.rate DESC`

product_rows, err := db.Query(query, name)

if err != nil {
        return nil, err
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Dont put qoutes when you are preparing your query. Just provide the value with qoutes and % sign. This will solve the problem. tried and tested.

Solution: 
query := `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
        FROM products AS p
        WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE $1 ORDER BY p.rate DESC`

```
product_rows, err := db.Query(query, "'%" + name + "%'")
```

I got my soltion from [this thread](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/503)

Comment: Just found out that the solution depends on the version of Golang because after upgrading golang to 1.10 my solution stopped working and I had to go for  '%' || $1 || '%' solution. So do try different solutions to make things work

Comment: This is probably vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345318/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-go-while-using-database-sql).

Comment: this is for sure a code vulnerable to SQL injection, please consider editing the answer

Answer (score -1):

This works for me

```
query := "SELECT ProductId,Name,Description,Price,SKU FROM Products WHERE Name LIKE ?"
rows, err := r.db.QueryContext(ctx, query, "%"+name+"%")
```

Comment: this code is vulnerable to SQL injections, please consider editing the answer

Answer (score -2):

```
query := `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
    FROM products AS p
    WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE $1 ORDER BY p.rate DESC`

product_rows, err := db.Query(query, '%' + name+ '%'))
```

Answer (score -3):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/503) your query must not contain '%' sign, but "name" parameter must be quoted by '%'

```
query := `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.description, p.price, p.image, p.rate
    FROM products AS p
    WHERE LOWER(p.name) LIKE $1 ORDER BY p.rate DESC`

product_rows, err := db.Query(query, fmt.Sprintf("%%%s%%", name))
```

Comment: Its unsafe, sqlinjection can happen in it