# How can I prevent SQL injection attacks in Go while using "database/sql"?

Tags: go, sql-injection

Building my first web-app and want to understand SQL injection better (https://github.com/astaxie/build-web-application-with-golang/blob/master/en/eBook/09.4.md).

How much protection against SQL injection do I get from just always using the 'database/sql' library and constructing queries using '?' instead of concatting strings?  What kind of SQL injection attacks will I still have to worry about in that case?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As long as you're using [Prepare](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Prepare) or [Query](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query), you're safe.

```
// this is safe
db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", req.FormValue("age"))
// this allows sql injection.
db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=" + req.FormValue("age"))
```

Comment: Exec also allow binding value without using Prepare. Is it safe, my guess is that it makes an implicite Prepare statement but I haven't look into the code

Comment: is there a way to make `fmt.Sprintf` safe.

Comment: @Entei not really, unless you manually process every param, there's no reason not to use prepared queries though.

Comment: @OneOfOne just wondered if it is possible to use the printf style of string manuplation. Thank you.

Comment: does the same apply with db.Exec? for example: `db.Exec("DELETE from books where pk = ?", r.FormValue("pk"))`

Comment: what about this in golang? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection

Comment: @AnikHasibul I'm not 100% sure, however Go generally handles that kind of things much much much better than php.

Comment: @OneOfOne I'm no expert in DBs, I found this issue discussion in the go posgres /lib/pq. Where they discuss that even using Query there are some vulnerabilities?  https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/248

Answer (score 7):

I agree with @Oneonone's answer.

If you are retrieving data, do something like:

```
db.Query("SELECT name FROM users WHERE age=?", req.FormValue("age"))
```

If you have to insert a lot of data safely, using the same query, this is where Prepare comes handy. you can do something like this:

```
tx, err := db.Begin()
if err != nil {
    return nil,err
}
stmt, err := tx.Prepare("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?)")
if err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return nil,err
}
defer 
for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    _, err = stmt.Exec(i, "dummy")
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil,err
    }
}
err = tx.Commit()
if err != nil {
    stmt.Close()
    tx.Rollback()
    return nil,err
}
stmt.Close()
return someValue, nil
```

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46476451/5466534

Answer (score -1):

There is an article about this on go.dev: [Avoiding SQL injection risk](https://go.dev/doc/database/sql-injection).

> You can avoid an SQL injection risk by providing SQL parameter values as sql package function arguments. Many functions in the sql package provide parameters for the SQL statement and for values to be used in that statement’s parameters (others provide a parameter for a prepared statement and parameters).
>
> Code in the following example uses the ? symbol as a placeholder for the id parameter, which is provided as a function argument:

```golang
// Correct format for executing an SQL statement with parameters.
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", id)
```

> sql package functions that perform database operations create prepared statements from the arguments you supply. At run time, the sql package turns the SQL statement into a prepared statement and sends it along with the parameter, which is separate.
>
> Note: Parameter placeholders vary depending on the DBMS and driver you’re using. For example, pq driver for Postgres accepts a placeholder form such as $1 instead of ?.
>
> You might be tempted to use a function from the fmt package to assemble the SQL statement as a string with parameters included – like this:

```golang
// SECURITY RISK!
rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = %s", id))
```

> This is not secure! When you do this, Go assembles the entire SQL statement, replacing the %s format verb with the parameter value, before sending the full statement to the DBMS. This poses an SQL injection risk because the code’s caller could send an unexpected SQL snippet as the id argument. That snippet could complete the SQL statement in unpredictable ways that are dangerous to your application.
>
> For example, by passing a certain %s value, you might end up with something like the following, which could return all user records in your database:

```sql
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = 1 OR 1=1;
```

Comment: It's good that you've sourced and quoted this content, but this doesn't really add anything that a comment with a link couldn't have done. See the help center article on [referencing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing): "Do *not* copy the complete text of sources... answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content"

Answer (score -2):

If prepared statements are not enough, you can use a query builder.

I created the [hotcoal package](https://github.com/motrboat/hotcoal), which helps you secure your handcrafted SQL against injection. It provides a minimal API and you can use it with any SQL library.