# How to prevent SQL Injection in PostgreSQL JSON/JSONB field?

Tags: postgresql, go, sql-injection

[How can I prevent SQL injection attacks in Go while using "database/sql"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345318/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-go-while-using-database-sql)

This solves the single value field problem because you can remove the quotes, but I can't do that filtering a JSON/JSONB field, like in the following because the `$1` is considered a string:

```
`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar @> '{"baz": "$1"}'`
```

The following works but it's prone to SQL Injection:

```
`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar @> '{"baz": "` + "qux" + `"}'`
```

How do I solve this?

---

**EDITED after @mkopriva's comment:**

How would I build this json `[{"foo": $1}]` with the `jsonb_*` functions? Tried the below without success:

```
jsonb_build_array(0, jsonb_build_object('foo', $1::text))::jsonb
```

There's no sql error. The filter just doesn't work. There's a way that I can check the builded sql? I'm using the `database/sql` native lib.

Comment: By using `json_build_object`/`jsonb_build_object` and similar functions instead of constructing the json from strings. E.g. `... bar @> json_build_object("bar", $1)`

Comment: Are there no prepared statements in Go? That's the king's way to avoiding SQL injection.

Comment: Remove the `0,` at the start of the `jsonb_build_array`; you’re creating `[0, {"foo": …}]`. Also, no need to cast `jsonb_build_array` to `jsonb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
type MyStruct struct {
    Baz string
}

func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://...")
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    s := MyStruct{
        Baz: "qux",
    }

    val, _ := json.Marshal(s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    if _, err := db.Exec("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar @> ?", val); err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
}
```

As a side note, `Exec` isn't for retrieval (although I kept it for you so the solution would match your example). Check out `db.Query` (Fantastic tutorial here: http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html)

Comment: I had to tweak a bit, and put a json tag to format the key in the struct, but it worked. Thanks. The @Ry-'s comment in the question also worked.

Comment: Glad you were able to get what you needed friend.