# Parameter with pattern matching syntax in a PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, go, pattern-matching, parameterized-query

Iam writing a golang program in which i query postgres database. I want to to use $1 to supply values and should have a pattern matching

```
Db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where name like %$1%", user)
```

it says:

> syntax error at or near "%"

Comment: "Some error" is not enough to define an error.

Comment: I did like this to get output
    Db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where name like $1", "%"+user+"%")
but isn't there any better and professional way to do it

Comment: it says syntax error at or near "%"

I did like this to get output

Db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where name like $1","%"+user+"%")

but isn't there any better and professional way to do it

Comment: which package you use ? Give us more detail about what is user... As said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214459/go-postgresql-like-query try to escape your like request like '%$1%'

Comment: Thanks for the link  Manawasp. Thats what i was lookin for exactly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go postgresql LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214459/go-postgresql-like-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, try

```
user := "%"+user+"%"

rows, err := Db.Query("SELECT * FROM table where name like $1", user)

if err!=nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```