# What's wrong with my Postgres query inside of golang (LIKE matching)

Tags: sql, go, psql

I've seen a very similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214459/go-postgresql-like-query), but I'm not certain what the pipes do in the command, and it didn't work for me anyway.

So, here's the code I've tried.

```
rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel.%'"))
```

And even though, I have no idea what it's for, I also tried with the pipes.

```
rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel. || %'"))
```

So, what it should be doing, is matching anything in that column that starts with camel., so `camel.*`

The error I'm getting for both examples is

```
pq: syntax error at or near "("
```

So i'm guessing for some reason it's passing in more of that line as the command than I would like....maybe a quote problem?  I've tried a few other things, but nothing has worked.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can we test a hunch? Try: `rows, err := db.Query(\`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel.%'\`)` and see if that works better

Comment: Same error, but thanks for taking a look :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [func Sprintf(format string, a ...interface{}) string](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)
>
> Sprintf formats according to a format specifier and returns the resulting string.

```
mt.Println(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel%'"))

//Output:
//SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel%!'(MISSING)
//Ofc postgres will complain
```

You do not need `fmt.Sprintf` in this case.

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel.%'")
```

works fine.

But if you really need to use `fmt.Sprintf` you must escape '%' with '%%'

```
rows, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE 'camel.%%'"))
```

Comment: When I use either of those examples, I get ```pq: operator does not exist: inet ~~ unknown```.  Looking into that error now, just figured I'd respond first.

Comment: ok, I needed to type cast ```mycolumn```.  So changing the query to ```SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn::text LIKE 'camel.%'```

Comment: Come on... Do NOT use any formatting to build a query string! Flashbacks of the old days of SQL Injection come back to haunt us. Use your SQL package's parameter assignments when running the query, so they are properly escaped. `rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE (?)", "camel.%")`

Comment: You are right, but question was about something else)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Query using prepared statements for security, you can concat using CONCAT :

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn LIKE CONCAT(?, '%')", camel)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the  `LIKE '%' || camel. || '%'`