# Postgres Node search query using LIKE, how to set %

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have a weird problem I encountered using Postgresql and Node. I would like to use LIKE in my query together with % at the beginning and end of searched term. I have no issue using it in the plain SQL:

THIS WORKS:

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE '%searchterm%' OR custom_id LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

However, using it in Node is a bit of challenge. I haven't been successful in resolving it yet:
THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
  getVehiclesSearch: async function({ search }) {
    let response;
    try {
      response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE %$1% OR custom_id LIKE %$1%`, [search]);
      if(response) return response.rows;
    } catch(error) {
      // handle error
      console.error(error);
      // do not throw anything
    }
  },
```

Doing above will produce: syntax error at or near "%"

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE '%${$1}%' OR custom_id LIKE '%${$1}%
```

Doing above will produce: $1 is not defined

```
SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE '%$1%' OR custom_id LIKE '%$1%'
```

Doing above will produce: bind message supplies 1 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 0

I kind of struggle factoring the % in so it won't crash the query. Simply run out of ideas after trying above and variables of those. Thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been already answered over here:
[Go postgresql LIKE query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214459/go-postgresql-like-query)

In this particular case:

```
      response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE '%'||$1||'%' OR custom_id LIKE '%'||$1||'%'`, [search]);
```

This would work.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing single quotes, also I don't recognize a db adapter you use, but you can use template literals (watch out for sql injection!!!)

```
response = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE module_imei LIKE '%${search}%' OR custom_id LIKE '%${search}%'`);
```

Comment: @I2ysho thank you for your help. I am using https://node-postgres.com/features/pooling and sql injection prevention is exactly in that second part of the query [search]. So your solution would work (that is if I would not be using $1, which I need exactly because of what you pointed out (SQL inections).